# google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Error opening file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying out Google Cloud Vision API for [Detect text in files (PDF/TIFF)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) using its Python sample, and came across this error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Error opening file: gs://input_folder/input.pdf

I am instantiating the client via the json key using

> client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=vision_credentials)

I have created the service account with the following permission: Owner, Storage Admin, Storage Object Admin, Storage Transfer Admin. Please note that I am utilising Google bucket.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 565, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "Error opening file: gs://input_folder/input.pdf."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1564912541.032000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.194.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1052,"grpc_message":"Error opening file: gs://input_folder/input.pdf.","grpc_status":7}"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notepad.py", line 105, in <module>
    async_detect_document("gs://input_folder/input.pdf", "gs://output_folder_results/")
  File "notepad.py", line 62, in async_detect_document
    requests=[async_request])
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision_v1\gapic\image_annotator_client.py", line 484, in async_batch_annotate_files
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 273, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 182, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Error opening file: gs://input_folder/input.pdf.
```

My codes:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud import storage
from google.protobuf import json_format
# Supported mime_types are: 'application/pdf' and 'image/tiff'
mime_type = 'application/pdf'

batch_size = 2

# Google credentials
VISION_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'C:\\Users\\Eva\\Desktop\\GoogleOCR\\cred.json'
vision_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=VISION_SCOPES)

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=vision_credentials)

# Sample code
def async_detect_document(gcs_source_uri, gcs_destination_uri):
    feature = vision.types.Feature(
        type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)

    gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=gcs_source_uri)
    print(gcs_source)
    input_config = vision.types.InputConfig(
        gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)

    gcs_destination = vision.types.GcsDestination(uri=gcs_destination_uri)
    print(gcs_destination)
    output_config = vision.types.OutputConfig(
        gcs_destination=gcs_destination, batch_size=batch_size)

    async_request = vision.types.AsyncAnnotateFileRequest(
        features=[feature], input_config=input_config,
        output_config=output_config)
    print(async_request)
    operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(
        requests=[async_request])

    print('Waiting for the operation to finish.')
    operation.result(timeout=180)

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    match = re.match(r'gs://([^/]+)/(.+)', gcs_destination_uri)
    bucket_name = match.group(1)
    prefix = match.group(2)

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    blob_list = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))
    print('Output files:')
    for blob in blob_list:
        print(blob.name)
.
    output = blob_list[1]

    json_string = output.download_as_string()
    response = json_format.Parse(
        json_string, vision.types.AnnotateFileResponse())

    first_page_response = response.responses[0]
    annotation = first_page_response.full_text_annotation

    print(u'Full text:\n{}'.format(
        annotation.text))

async_detect_document("gs://input_folder/input.pdf", "gs://output_folder_results/")
```

**Update:** I tried setting the bucket object public access to AllUsers, and am still receiving the same error line

**Update 2:** Posted full traceback error

**Update 3:** Posted my codes

Comment: From which environment are you running your script? Is your bucket in the same project as the service account or in another project?

Comment: @Christopher i'm running the script through anaconda. Yes my bucket and service account are under the same project.

Comment: I could not think of any reason why would it fail considering the SA is already owner of the project, unless the script is picking up a credential which does not have access to your GCS bucket. You may want to check the bucket's inherited owners/permissions to see whether the service account is there

Comment: Are you setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable with the route path the service account credentials?

Comment: @Christopher I have checked and it is correctly assigned

Comment: @llompalles yes I have set environment variable to the correct json credential file

Comment: Update: I tried setting the bucket object to allusers public access, and am still receiving the same error line

Comment: Could you post the full traceback error?

Comment: @llompalles hey thanks for your efforts. i have posted the full traceback error

Comment: could you also share the code you are using? (the minimum required for a reproduction) Sanitizing any sensitive information that you may have (keys, passwords, secrets, project-id...).

Comment: @Mayeru hi, i've shared my codes. please take a look. there wasn't much but i had replaced sensitive information with dummies

Comment: @vvac thank you, I have run your code, without issue. A couple of things: 1.- you have a dot (.) in the middle of the code. 2- The var "re" is not initialized. 
I was able to run the function AsyncAnnotateFileRequest() (this is the one that fails for you) after the authentication process you have declared, however I'm using a service account with "owner" role. Please check that the service account that you are using has the proper permissions to list/see the buckets/objects. Also, where are you running this code from? a Cloud function or a Compute Engine instance? ...

Comment: (if is the last one please check that you have the Vision/Storage API enabled for that instance)

Comment: @Mayeru thanks for your input!! I was running it locally, now I have just created a Compute Engine instance to proceed. Just to clarify, as long as my APIs are enabled at 'API and Services', that will be sufficient?

Comment: @vvac running it locally should also work as long as you are using a service account with the proper permissions. But you can try using a Compute Engine instance to rule out any misconfiguration that might be happening locally. You'll need 3 things (aside of the proper python dependencies installed):  1-. Proper permissions on the service account (it needs to able to access your buckets and the objects inside it, so it has to have the "storage.admin" role or something higher) to be sure is not a role permission issue you can try with a service account with the "owner" role.

Comment: 2-. The Vision API enabled for your project (the ones listed on "API and Services" ). 
3-. If you are trying in Compute Engine, be sure that the service account assigned to the instance is the one that you are going to use for the authentication and that your instance is set to "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" (to rule out the scope as an issue, you can limit this later) under "Cloud API access scopes" (click to edit your instance, you will see it at the end, If is not set like that you'll have to stop your instance in order to edit this field).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `credentials` argument does what you think it does. If you have your credentials in a JSON file, you need to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with the path to the JSON file. Alternatively, if you have the JSON file *contents* loaded into a variable, e.g. `info`, you can do:

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

vision_credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_info(info)
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=vision_credentials)
```

Comment: I have already set the environment variable and alternatively have the codes to load the JSON file contents into the vision_credentials variable, similar to what you suggested.

Comment: @vvac ok, sorry it didn't work for you, but it _does_ work. Simply loading the JSON file contents into the vision_credentials variable will not work, it needs to be used to create a `Credentials` object. That was not well-documented (if at all?) and took me some work to figure out. But maybe you're having some other error. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, despite having correctly configured all my environments. I was utilizing the JSON file supplied by my employer, and I received the necessary permissions in the API key. Nevertheless, I consistently encountered the same error. To address this problem, I took the initiative to create my own account, enabled billing, and provided my payment details. It's worth noting that you'll receive a $405 free trial that lasts for 90 days. Even after this trial period expires, you won't incur automatic charges. You'll be presented with the choice to activate billing, which you can deactivate at any time to close your account.